# C++ serialize object with vector causes double free corruption

Tags: c++, serialization

I'm trying to serialize and deserialize an object which contains a vector
using ofstream and ifstream. The process of serialization works like a charm, but as soon as I call the read method of ifstream, I get a double free or corruption exception. This is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class A
{
private:

    vector<int> v;

public:

    void add(int e) {
        v.push_back(e);
    }

    void print() {
        vector<int>::iterator it;

        cout << "[" << v.at(0);

        for(it = v.begin()+1; it!=v.end(); ++it)
            cout << "," << *it;

        cout << "]" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    A s; 

    ofstream ofs;
    ifstream ifs;

    for (int i=1; i<= 10; i++)
        a.add(i);

    a.print();

    ofs.open("s.bin", ios::binary);
    ofs.write((char *) &a, sizeof(a));
    ofs.close();

    ifs.open("s.bin", ios::binary);
    ifs.read((char *) &s, sizeof(s));
    ifs.close();

    cout << "s: ";
    s.print();  


    return 0;
}
```

A strange behavior is, that the program prints out the deserialized object. This is my outout:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
s: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
*** Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x000000000187c080 ***
```

Any ideas what causes this problem? I'm clueless.

Comment: The ultimate cause is that you're *not* serialising the object but just writing its in-memory representation to disk.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thank you for this hint. I'll have a look at the boost library as Tony mentioned in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have *undefined behaviour*, and it appears that in your particular case what's *probably* happening is that the pointers to `a`'s dynamically allocated buffer - which stores the numbers - are written to disk then read back in over the memory for `s`, such that the `s` object believes itself the rightful owner of the same dynamic buffer as `a`.

As execution leaves the scope of `main()`, `s`'s destructor runs  and releases that buffer, then `a`'s destructor tries to release the same buffer, hence "double free".

If you want to serialise elements properly, I recommend the boost::serialize library.  Failing that, at least write `a.size() * sizeof a[0]` bytes from `a.data()`: the actual contained data and not the `vector` object managing that buffer.  Afterwards, use `resize` on `s` to get it to allocate suitable memory and read the same number of bytes to `s.data()`.  If you wanted to generalise the code to support varying numbers of elements you're write out the `size` first, and if you want portability you'd use `hton`/`ntoh` to handle endianness.

Comment: You're right. I've fixed it so far by moving the serialization and deserialization in two different methods, which fixed the error. But to get it right, I'll have a look at the boost library, thank you!